# Odoo 8 override _amount_line

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to override the `_amount_line` function in `sale.order.line` model in order to add custum logic.

Here is my code:

```py
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    def _amount_line(self):
        tax_obj = self.env['account.tax']
        cur_obj = self.env['res.currency']
        res = {}
        for line in self:
            print line.tax_id
            price = self._calc_line_base_price(line)
            qty = self._calc_line_quantity(line)
            print" price:{} & quantity: {}".format(price,qty)
            taxes = tax_obj.compute_all(line.tax_id, price, qty,
                                        line.product_id,
                                        line.order_id.partner_id)
            cur = line.order_id.pricelist_id.currency_id
            res[line.id] = cur_obj.round(cur, taxes['total'])
        return res

    remise_palier = fields.Float('Remise palier (%)')
    remise_total = fields.Float('Remise totale (%)')
    price_subtotal = fields.Float(compute='_amount_line', string='Subtotal')
```

When i run Odoo, i get that error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made mistake in compute_all method calling.

This method should be like this,

```
@api.multi
def _amount_line(self):
    tax_obj = self.env['account.tax']
    cur_obj = self.env['res.currency']
    for line in self:
        print line.tax_id
        price = self._calc_line_base_price(line)
        qty = self._calc_line_quantity(line)
        print" price:{} & quantity: {}".format(price,qty)
        taxes = line.tax_id.compute_all(price, qty, line.product_id, line.order_id.partner_id)        
        cur = line.order_id.pricelist_id.currency_id
        line.price_subtotal = cur.round(taxes['total'])
```

Comment: Hi. it didn't work. Here is the original line in sale.py `taxes = tax_obj.compute_all(cr, uid, line.tax_id, price, qty,
                                        line.product_id,
                                        line.order_id.partner_id)`

Comment: Sorry, it works but i'm getting an other error now: `return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs) TypeError: round() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: `line.price_subtotal = cur.round(taxes['total'])` is that not worked ?

Comment: I didn't see that you modified that liine too. i used `cur_obj.round(cur, taxes['total'])` .That is why it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo V8+ the `compute_all` call should be on the taxes itself. You don't need to call it as "class method". Following snippet should work for you:

```py
@api.multi
# @api.depends() use it for recomputation triggers
def _amount_line(self):
    for line in self:
        print line.tax_id
        price = self._calc_line_base_price(line)
        qty = self._calc_line_quantity(line)
        print" price:{} & quantity: {}".format(price,qty)
        taxes = line.tax_id.compute_all(
            price, qty, line.product_id, line.order_id.partner_id)
        cur = line.order_id.pricelist_id.currency_id
        line.price_subtotal = cur.round(taxes['total'])
```

**Edit**: You don't need to return something on new API computed field functions. Just assign the values to the computed field(s).

**Edit2**: There is a new API style method for currency `round()`, too. I've changed my snippet.

Comment: Hi @CZoellner it gives me now `return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: round() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: I Think that it is the same problem, let me take a look

Comment: It's edited. You have to call `round` on the currency object with the new API.

Comment: I just saw, that it is the same answer as by @Emipro. His answer should work, too. If so, mark his answer as correct answer.

Comment: Thank you @CZoellner. One last question , where can i find the currency object (especially `round` method)? i want to apply my custum discount to the subtotal price.

Comment: The model `res.currency` is defined under `odoo/(openerp)/addons/base/res`.