# Try return value of product in sale order line for Odoo10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

I have a Many2one('product_weight') field in sales order based on product.product. And i try to return that field values in sales order line(product).  In product.template i added a check_box('is_weight'). So, in sales order for 'product_weight' only weight products are available. So, how to return that 'product_weight' value in sales order line(product_id) ?

**My code is here:**

```
class sale_order_pet(models.Model):

    _inherit = "sale.order"

 product_weight = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Service products', domain="[('is_weight','=',True)]")



    @api.onchange('product_id')

    def _onchange_action_weight_add(self):

        res = self.product_id

        print"resss:::", res

        if res:

            line_values = {'product_id': self.product_weight.id,

                           }

            sale_order_line = self.env['sale.order.line'].create(line_values)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want show product weight in sale order line?

Comment: Yes, i want to show product_weight in product_id(sales order line)

Comment: @PAWANSHARMA you can not create record in onchange , if you want to show only product that are `check_box('is_weight')` so simply find all that product ids and return domain like . `[('id', 'in', ids)]`]

Comment: Hello @Heroic , i already filter my product_weight with domain. But, problem is related to onchange functionality. How to apply onchange on product_weight so after select Product_weight it is automatically fill in the sales order line(product_id)?

Comment: @PAWANSHARMA so can add it to order like . `self.order_line = [(0,0,{'product_id': self.product_weight.id})]`

Comment: hello pawan 
check below link i hope it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754720/odoo-8-override-amount-line

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
    @api.onchange('product_weight ')

    def _onchange_action_weight_add(self):

        res = self.product_id

        print"resss:::", res

        if res:

            line_values = {
                  'order_id': self.id,
                  'product_id': self.product_weight.id,

                           }

            sale_order_line = self.env['sale.order.line'].create(line_values)
```

Comment: Hello Karara, here i not getting any id print on terminal. And one think is also tell me, where i call this onchange function becouse it should return at sales order line. So, we call this onchange function on sales order line.
Thanks Karara...!!

Comment: you use this onchange in sale order

Comment: Yes i applied that, but value not return in sales order line

Comment: You need to add 'name'
            'product_uom_qty'
            'product_uom'

            'price_unit'

Comment: Yes, added that already, here it is:
@api.multi
def _prepare_productpack_order_line_procurement(self, pack, group_id=False):
        self.ensure_one()
      date_planned = datetime.strptime(self.order_id.date_order, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)\
            + timedelta(days=self.customer_lead or 0.0) - timedelta(days=self.order_id.company_id.security_lead)
        return {
            'name': pack.name,
            'origin': self.order_id.name,
            'product_id': pack.id,
            'product_qty': self.product_uom_qty,
            'product_uom': pack.uom_id.id,
        }

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

**sale_order_line.py**

> class sale_order_line(models.Model):
>
> _inherit = "sale.order.line"
>
> product_weight = fields.Float('Weight',
>
> related='product_id.weight',
>
> digits=dp.get_precision('Product Weight'),
>
> help="The weight of the contents in Kg, not including any packaging,
> etc.")

And for xml you can inherit sale.view_order_form:

**sale_order_views.xml**

```
<record id="view_weight_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_id']"
                  position="after">
                    <field name="product_weight "/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

I hope This can help you...